# Android getActiveNotifications throws SecurityException

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-notifications, android-securityexception, notification-listener

I have a NotificationService class that listens to notifications. However when I call getActiveNotifications(), it throws a SecurityException. Yes I have checked for permission before calling this method.

I use AsyncTask inside NotificationService to get notification. Code is below.

```
private class AsyncProcessNotification extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            int notificationType = MainApplication.settingNotificationType;
            MainApplication.clearNotificationItems();

            if (MainApplication.settingNotificationType == Constants.KEY_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_DISABLED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Notifications disabled");
                return null;
            }

            if (PermissionHelper.isNotificationPermissionGranted(getApplicationContext())) {
                if (getActiveNotifications() == null || getActiveNotifications().length == 0) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "No notifications found");
                    return null;
                }

                Log.i(TAG, "Getting " + getActiveNotifications().length +" notifications");
                Log.i(TAG, "Notification type  " + notificationType);
                for (StatusBarNotification statusBarNotification : getActiveNotifications()) {
                    // Process notifications
                }
            } else {
                //
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Intent notify = new Intent(Constants.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER);
            sendBroadcast(notify);
        }
    }
```

Strange thing is **according to 
Crashlytics**, sometimes it fails at `if (getActiveNotifications() == null || getActiveNotifications().length == 0)` and sometimes it fails at `Log.i(TAG, "Getting " + getActiveNotifications().length +" notifications");`

To check permission, I use following method.

```
public static boolean isNotificationPermissionGranted(Context context) {
        Set<String> appList = NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(context);
        for (String l:appList) {
            if (l.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Disallowed call from unknown notification listener: android.service.notification.INotificationListener$Stub$Proxy@3e9880d
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
       at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNotificationsFromListener(INotificationManager.java:1046)
       at android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService.getActiveNotifications(NotificationListenerService.java:467)
       at android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService.getActiveNotifications(NotificationListenerService.java:420)
       at com.afd.app.lockscreen.ios11.lib.service.NotificationService$AsyncProcessNotification.doInBackground(NotificationService.java:120)
       at com.afd.app.lockscreen.ios11.lib.service.NotificationService$AsyncProcessNotification.doInBackground(NotificationService.java:97)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I know I must be doing something stupid but can not figure out what. Can somebody please help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @Juan Trace added.

Comment: According to doc getActiveNotifications() has to be called after onListenerConnected() and before onListenerDisconnected(). As you are running in AsyncTask, are you taking care of this for example canceling thte task upon disconnection?

Comment: @VajiraLasantha Were you able to solve this ? I am getting the same error

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

> I hit the same error in my notification listener service. I was able
>   to solve it by waiting for the listener service to get connected to the
>   notification manager before calling any of the
>   **NotificationListenerService** methods.

```
@Override
public void onListenerConnected() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Listener connected");
    listenerConnected = true;
}

private class AsyncProcessNotification extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
              ...
            // wait until our notification listener service is connected
            // to the notification manager
            Log.i(TAG, "Waiting for listener to be connected...");

            while(!listenerConnected);

            // Call getActiveNotifications after this
            for (StatusBarNotification sbn : getActiveNotifications()) {
                   processNotifications(sbn);
            }
    }

    // rest of the AsyncTask here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @niranjan-nagaraju writen, you need to check `sIsConnected` before canceling notification.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b408e8ecd22853faa70e97d0596aac9e7dcf5596/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationListeners.java#175